# Not able to display time on X-Axis using Matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am reading some data from the file, and then I have to plot this data for visual representation.
The data in the file is present in the following format:

```
16:08:45,64,31.2
16:08:46,60,29.3
16:08:47,60,29.3
16:08:48,60,29.3
16:08:49,60,29.3
.
.
```

This data is present in a file with the current date.
The file consist of time (Hour:Minute:Second), Adc Counts, Temperature Value

I used the following code to read the data from the file using Pandas.

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

year = 2018     # For 2018
'''
month = input ('Enter Month : ')
date = input ('Enter Date : ')
month = int(month)
date = int(date)
'''
# Hardcoded Values for Testing Purpose
month = 1
date = 20

headers = ['Time', 'ADC', 'Temperature']
filename = '%.2d-%.2d-%.2d.txt' % (month, date, year-2000)
print (filename)

try:
    df = pd.read_table( filename, ',', names=headers,\
                        engine='python', header=None)
except:
    print ('No Such File in Database')
    print ('Exiting Program')
    exit()

FMT = '%H:%M:%S'
df['Time'] = df['Time'].map(lambda x: datetime.strptime(str(x), FMT))
df['Time'] = df['Time'].map(lambda x: x.replace(day=date, month=month, year=year))

plt.plot( df['Time'], df['ADC'])

plt.ylim( [0,200])
#plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

[image: Graph Generated]

I didn't get why the x-axis doesn't have correct values.
Is it due to the reason, that samples are too close ( 1sec) apart?

I only want time information on X-Axis.
Please suggest how I can get that.
Thanks in advance.

**Update:**

From comments, I am able to find the reason, why this is happening.
Pandas is treating my Date and Time as `timestamp` object while for plotting it with `Matplotlib`, it should be `datetime` object.
My problem will get solved if I am able to convert `df['Time']` from `Timestamp` to `datetime`.
I searched online and found the `pd.to_datetime`, will do this work for me, but unfortunately, it doesn't work.
The following commands will list what I have done.

```
>>> x = pd.Timestamp( "2018-01-20")
>>> x
Timestamp('2018-01-20 00:00:00')
>>> pd.to_datetime( x, format="%Y-%m-%d")
Timestamp('2018-01-20 00:00:00')
```

As you can see above, i still get `timestamp` object
I searched again to check why it is not working, then I found that the following line will work.

```
>>> x = pd.Timestamp( "2018-01-20")
>>> y = pd.to_datetime( x, format="%Y-%m-%d")
>>> y.to_datetime()

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "D:\Program Files\Python36\lib\idlelib\run.py", line 457
    exec(code, self.locals)
FutureWarning: to_datetime is deprecated. Use self.to_pydatetime()
datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 20, 0, 0)
>>>
```

To remove this warning following commands can be used.

```
>>> x = pd.Timestamp( "2018-01-20")
>>> y = pd.to_datetime( x, format="%Y-%m-%d")
>>> y.to_pydatetime()
datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 20, 0, 0)
```

Now I tested these command in my project to see if this is working with my dataframe or not, I just took one value for testing.

```
>>> x = df['Time'][0].to_pydatetime()
>>> x
datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 20, 16, 8, 45)
```

So, yes it is working, now I have to apply this on complete column of dataframe and I used the following command.

```
>>> df['New'] = df['Time'].apply(lambda x: x.to_pydatetime())
>>> df['New'][0]
Timestamp('2018-01-20 16:08:45')
```

But it's still the same.
I am newbie, so I am not able to understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Matplotlib uses `datetime` objects to plot dates. If you supply anything else, as done here, how would it even know that it should display dates on the x axis? If you want further help than that, please provide a [mcve] of the issue.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Actually I thought it is a `datetime` object, as i used some functions related to `datetime` object. But now I checked it, and it was `TimeStamp` object. I will now convert this into `datetime` object and I hope that will solve this problem. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Can you please help me. What mistake I have done.
I updated the question with more details.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we need a minimal, verifiable example:

```
u = u"""16:08:45,64,31.2
16:08:46,54,29.3
16:08:47,36,34.3
16:08:48,67,36.3
16:08:49,87,29.3"""

import io
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

year = 2018
month = 1
date = 20

headers = ['Time', 'ADC', 'Temperature']

df = pd.read_table(io.StringIO(u), ',', names=headers,\
                        engine='python', header=None)

FMT = '%H:%M:%S'
df['Time'] = df['Time'].map(lambda x: datetime.strptime(str(x), FMT))
df['Time'] = df['Time'].map(lambda x: x.replace(day=date, month=month, year=year))

plt.plot( df['Time'], df['ADC'])

plt.ylim( [20,100])
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

Running this code with pandas 0.20.1 and matplotlib 2.1, the following plot is produced, which looks as desired:

[image]

The reason this works, even if the dates are pandas time stamps is that matplotlib uses the pandas converters internally, if they are available. 
If not, one may first try to load them manually,

```
import pandas.plotting._converter as pandacnv
pandacnv.register()
```

If this also fails, one may indeed try to convert the timestamps to datetime objects.

```
dt = [x.to_pydatetime() for x in df['Time']]
plt.plot( dt, df['ADC'])
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.
I copied and paste the code shared by you with the changes you done.
Actually I think there is no changes, as  I haven't shared the log file with you, so you have to do these changes.
So I run your code and still i see the same display on X-Axis.
Actually I am using Python 3.6.3,  after this I installed Python 2.7.14 and my code works fine.
Is there something we can do with this..

Comment: **Matplotlib uses datetime objects to plot dates. If you supply anything else, as done here, how would it even know that it should display dates on the x axis? **
Are these lines still valid, I am little confused, as to me it looks that plot should work fine in both the cases.

Comment: Whether those are valid or not, depends on the pandas version in use. To be on the safe side, use `datetime` objects. There are 3 options in my answer, which one are you talking about here?

Comment: No, the problem is not on matplotlib's side. It is on pandas' side. Depending on the version of pandas you use, you may get different results. What is "both cases"? As said, the only reliable option is to use `datetime`, anything else might depend on the pandas version.

Comment: I am using '0.21.0' version of Pandas.
Thanks for your help.
First Option is not working on Python 3.6.3 rest two are working.
And on Python 1st one is working so I didn't tested 2nd and 3rd.
I am really thankful to you. I wasted my complete day on this, but finally it is working.
Yes you are right, Matplotlib is fine, it's on Pandas side.

Comment: Update:
I was doing all this thing on my laptop with updated packages, I tested the same python code on my Desktop having Pandas version '0.19.2' and it was working fine on that.